# Which FFT algorithm does this code use?

Tags: php, fft

I found it online and there are no comments.

It comes with a Complex.class that basically simulates complex numbers and their operations.

I'd like to comment it myself but I really can't identify which algorithm is being used. I went online and found that the Cooley-Tukey algorithm is the most widespread, but I'm not sure that this code uses it.

```
private $dim;
private $p;
private $ind;
private $func;
private $w1;
private $w1i;
private $w2;

public function __construct($dim) {
    $this->dim = $dim;
    $this->p = log($this->dim, 2);
}


public function fft($func) {
    $this->func = $func;

    // Copying func in w1 as a complex.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->dim; $i++)
        $this->w1[$i] = new Complex($func[$i], 0);

    $w[0] = new Complex(1, 0);
    $w[1] = new Complex(cos((-2 * M_PI) / $this->dim), sin((-2 * M_PI) / $this->dim));

    for ($i = 2; $i < $this->dim; $i++)
        $w[$i] = Complex::Cmul($w[$i-1], $w[1]);

    return $this->calculate($w);
}

private function calculate($w) {
    $k = 1;
    $ind[0] = 0;

    for ($j = 0; $j < $this->p; $j++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $k; $i++) {
            $ind[$i] *= 2;
            $ind[$i+$k] = $ind[$i] + 1;
        }
        $k *= 2;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->p; $i++) {
        $indw = 0;
        for ($j = 0; $j < pow(2, $i); $j++) {
            $inf = ($this->dim / pow(2, $i)) * $j;
            $sup = (($this->dim / pow(2, $i)) * ($j+1)) - 1;
            $comp = ($this->dim / pow(2, $i)) / 2;

            for ($k = $inf; $k <= floor($inf+(($sup-$inf)/2)); $k++)
                $this->w2[$k] = Complex::Cadd(Complex::Cmul($this->w1[$k], $w[0]), Complex::Cmul($this->w1[$k+$comp], $w[$ind[$indw]]));    

            $indw++;

            for ($k = floor($inf+(($sup-$inf)/2)+1); $k <= $sup; $k++)
                $this->w2[$k] = Complex::Cadd(Complex::Cmul($this->w1[$k], $w[$ind[$indw]]), Complex::Cmul($this->w1[$k-$comp], $w[0]));

            $indw++;
        }

        for($j = 0; $j < $this->dim; $j++)
            $this->w1[$j] = $this->w2[$j];
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->dim; $i++)
        $this->w1[$i] = $this->w2[$ind[$i]];

    return $this->w1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a radix 2 FFT implementation based on the Cooley-Tukey algorithm, with the work being done in the function "compute".  It will only work with FFT lengths that are a power of 2, although I don't see any parameter checking in the function itself.

$i iterates over the multiple FFT passes (of which there are log2(N) where N is the length of the FFT), and in each pass, the twiddle factors (stored in $w) are multiplied by the output from the previous stage before finding the complex sum and difference.

There are much better implementations of FFTs out there, such as FFTW, that implement a mixed radix approach, which allow an arbitrary length of FFT to be computed.